# Why do Aurelia plugins load slowly in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, aurelia

I'm working on my first Aurelia app, targeting the ASP.NET Core 2.0 platform, using TypeScript as the transpiler, and hosting it in IIS 7.5. So far, I just have "Hello World" functionality, but I've already noticed something odd. I've tested it so far in Chrome 61.0.3163.79 64-bit, Firefox 51.0.1 32-bit, Vivaldi 1.11.917.43 32-bit, and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18762, both 32- and 64-bit (we're still on Windows 7 [Enterprise 64-bit with SP1], so I can't test Edge). In all of the browsers except IE, the app's initial page (just displaying "Hello World") loads in appx. 500 ms. In IE (both 32- and 64-bit), it takes between 15 and 20 seconds. Looking at the console in the developer tools, it seems to take an abnormally long time to load the Aurelia plugins. For example, the wait between the

```
DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
```

message and the

```
DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
```

message is 4-5 seconds. In all other browsers I've tested, it's essentially instantaneous. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with caching, as I've been clearing the browser cache before each test.

Unfortunately, IE11 is my company's standard browser, so I don't really have the option of ignoring it. Can anyone shed any light on this and/or propose a solution or workaround?

Comment: What bundler did you choose ? Is it requirejs / systemjs or webpack ?

Comment: could be bluebird long stack traces causing the issue, see https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/448